# Store Linq Query in a list c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class from my entity Framework, i want to store this result of my linq query in list to display it in my web form, i get this error message:

> Error   4   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'    \App_Code\Models\PackageModel.cs

this is my code:

thanks for a helping.

```
public partial class Package
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }
    public int SessionID { get; set; }
    public int LessonsID { get; set; }
    public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}

public List<Package> GetAllItemPackage()
{
    try
    {
        using (MusicSchoolEntities db = new MusicSchoolEntities())
        {
            List<Package> packages = (from x in db.Packages                                           
                                      join y in db.Schools on x.SchoolID equals y.ID
                                      join z in db.Sessions on x.SessionID equals z.ID
                                      join w in db.Lessons on x.LessonsID equals w.ID
                                      join q in db.Courses on w.CourseID equals q.ID
                                      select new { SchoolTitle = y.TitleEn , 
                                                   SessionName = z.NameEn, 
                                                   CourseTitle = q.TitleEn, 
                                                   LessonPeriod = w.PeriodEn, 
                                                   LessonPrice = w.PriceEn, 
                                                   LessonDesc = w.DescriptionEn, 
                                                   LessonPaymtd = w.PayMtdEn}).ToList();
                return packages;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `select new` and not `select x`? If you want to return `Package`s you have to return `Package`s.

Comment: i have joint selection to display my info in web form, the info comes from different table.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's basic knowledge that you should return what you specify as return type. You shouldn't be surprised that the compiler complains if you don't.

Comment: @Gert Arnold i'm beginner in web dev, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems there.

1. First is that your code return an anonymous type but you are trying
   to populate a `List<Package>` - That is why you get the exception.
2. Secondly, the data you are trying to populate isn't like the `Package` class that you have so if you want to return such a list from a function you should create a **new type of class** to have all those properties.

So:

```
List<YourClass> packages = (from x in db.Packages                                           
                          join y in db.Schools on x.SchoolID equals y.ID
                          join z in db.Sessions on x.SessionID equals z.ID
                          join w in db.Lessons on x.LessonsID equals w.ID
                          join q in db.Courses on w.CourseID equals q.ID
                          select new YourClass
                          {
                              SchoolTitle = y.TitleEn , 
                              SessionName = z.NameEn, 
                              CourseTitle = q.TitleEn, 
                              LessonPeriod = w.PeriodEn, 
                              LessonPrice = w.PriceEn, 
                              LessonDesc = w.DescriptionEn, 
                              LessonPaymtd = w.PayMtdEn
                          }).ToList();
return packages;
```

*And of course `GetAllItemPackage` should return: `List<YourClass>` and not `List<Package>`*

Comment: i get Package does not contain a definition for 'SchoolTitle' , the same for all selection items.

Comment: @AissamAitkacem - Great :)